# Cant fetch from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know why cant find how get friends Ids.
her is my code:

```
func fetchUsers() {
    
    let ref = Firebase.Database.database().reference()
    
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userID = userId
    
    ref.child("Users").child(userID).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        print("snapshot...\(snapshot)")
        let user = User()
        
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            user.currentUserFriends = dictionary["Friends"] as? String
            print("dictionary...\(user.currentUserFriends ?? "no value")")
        }
    }
}
```

and my tree from firebase is Users-Uid-Friends-friendID-true.

Comment: do u get any error message? Did u check ```userId``` is nil or not?

Comment: Since you don't show what `User` is, I can only guess 
that the word you use in `user.currentUserFriends` suggests an array of friends, not just one.
So you could try `user.currentUserFriends = dictionary["Friends"] as? [String]`

Comment: When I print snapshot it gets me all snaps correctly, but when I print dictionary it prints no value.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
 ref.child("Users").child(userID!).child("Friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            print("snapshot...\(snapshot)")
            let dic = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            for (key,value) in dic{
                let friendsID = key
                let friendBool = value
                print("key is \(friendsID) and value is \(friendBool)")
                let user = User()
                user.currentUserFriends = key as? String
            }
        }
```